# My HP trackpoint is sending keystrokes, how can I disable it?

Tags: linux, xorg, mouse

I am running Debian stretch (with a newer kernel, 4.14) on an HP 8460p.  The trackpoint (pointing stick), when pushed left or right, seems to send a very long stream of F9 or F10 keys, possibly along with other keys, preventing me from using the keyboard until I unjam it by switching VTs.  How can I disable the trackpoint functionality?  It doesn't seem to have an associated xinput device, and the properties on "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" or "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard" don't mention any trackpoint settings.

```
# xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP HD Webcam [Fixed]: HP HD Web           id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                            id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]

# dpkg -l | grep xserver-xorg-input
ii  xserver-xorg-input-evdev        1:2.10.5-1     amd64        X.Org X server -- evdev input driver
ii  xserver-xorg-input-synaptics    1.9.0-1+b1     amd64        Synaptics TouchPad driver for X.Org server
```

Answer (score -1):

Turn the laptop off (do not reboot), keep it off briefly, then turn it back on, at which point hopefully a

```
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

xinput device will reappear and trackpoint movements are no longer sent as keystrokes.